# Location of image in exported project folder

Tags: java, image, class, directory

In my current code I write the specific location of the images I want to use in my project, now, these locations are only correct until I move the image to a different directory or open the application in a different computer.

Where do I place the images (where to place them in the exported folder) I want to use in my project?

The exported project is a zip file, once extracted, I have 2 folders within the extracted folder, one named nbproject other is src, one text file named build another .mf file called manifest inside nbproject I have two text files and two .properties files inside src I have my four classes.

Where do I put the images I want to use in the project? And once I place them, what directory do I write in my project?

Here's an example of how I use an image:

```
// Main menu background image

bgg[0] = new ImageIcon("D:/NetBeans/NetBeans projects/Java/Project Images/bg option for Vanguard.jpg").getImage();
```

And then I draw the image all over the screen

My exported folder contents:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti2NE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAMjO.png

EDIT: Thought it worked but it keeps giving an exception on other people's computers, perhaps this isn't the reason beause I moved the images around in my PC and it worked but still.

Comment: Can you draw a make a directory structure that relates your Java file to images so we can see the hierarchy?

Comment: Not even sure what you mean, to be honest. 
But I'll give it a shot, hopefully I understood.

Comment: I mean show us the contents of every folder in your project.

Comment: Where is the image folder?

Comment: You mean the "Project Images" folder? or..?

Comment: Yeah, just refer to my answer below and move the folder with the Java files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing the directory in your code.

```
bgg[0] = new ImageIcon("D:/NetBeans/NetBeans projects/Java/Project Images/bg option for Vanguard.jpg").getImage();
```

When you run the project in another computer or move the image to another location, the program can't find the path to the picture, so there is an error. Instead of using the full path. Copy the images to your project folder and use relative paths.For instance : "images/Vanguard.jpg".

Comment: Ye, but where exactly do I place them in the project folder? In src? In nbproject? That's my question.

Comment: whenever you like, you can use net beans solution explorer , or simply go and use a file explorer to create a new folder "images" inside your project folder, and copy your images there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a strict path, use a relative path like so:

`Main.java`

```
String path = "Project Images/bg option for Vanguard.jpg";
bgg[0] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path)).getImage();
```

In order for this to be loaded, you must place a folder called `Project Images` in the directory in which your Java files are. Then place the image `bg option for Vanguard.jpg` in this folder. Be sure to compile the program in you IDE so it can make a copy for the compiled version.

Comment: Ye, I know I shouldn't use a strict path, that's the whole point of my question. Anyway, thank you for the advice, I'll give it a shot and let you know if it worked.

EDIT: It tells me that the URL cannot be converted to a string.

Comment: Gives me an exception. :/

Comment: What exception? Perhaps, you did not name the file according to the path I gave you.

Comment: Give me a link to all your source code and images so I can fix it up for you.

Comment: Never mind it. I solved it all. 
I used a kinda different method.

Comment: //  // Main menu background
        java.net.URL imageURL = getClass().getResource("Project Images/bg option for Vanguard.jpg");   
        if(imageURL != null)
        {
            bgg2 = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
            bgg[0] = bgg2.getImage();
        }//

Answer (score 0):

The path where your program looks for resources can depend on how you run the program. If you ran it via console/terminal the initial path starts at the path of the *.class file you ran. If you run it from an IDE this path may change, in Eclipse the path starts at the Project dir and **not** the src folder. You can find out the exact path by calling `System.getProperty("user.dir")` that will return the current working path as a `String`.